# Invalid shape error plotting 2D image in python for MNIST Sign Language dataset having PIXEL VALUES AS COLUMNS

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection

[I have a MNIST Sign Language dataset with pixel values as columns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BNDI.png)

I get the error when I try to plot an image at one of the indexes as follows:

```
#Training dataset
dfr = pd.read_csv("sign_mnist_train.csv")
X_train_orig = dfr.iloc[:,1:]
Y_train_orig = dfr['label']

#Testing dataset
dfe = pd.read_csv("sign_mnist_test.csv")
X_test_orig = dfe.iloc[:,1:]
Y_test_orig = dfe['label']

#shapes of dataset
print(dfr.shape) #(27455, 785)
print(dfe.shape) #(7172, 785)

#Example of a picture
index = 1
plt.imshow(X_train_orig.iloc[index])



#TypeError: Invalid shape (784,) for image data
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the image you are trying to plot is a flattened one corresponding to [B, N], where N is 1x28x28, and B is 27455 which is your image size (27455, 784). This is fine if you want to feed it to a Linear layer of 784 long vector. To plot this image you have to reshape it to correspond to [27455, 1, 28, 28]. You can try this out:

```
image = X_train_orig.iloc[index]
image = np.reshape(image.values, (28, 28))
plt.imshow(image)
```